# How can I get width and height for multiple images in a folder using matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

How can I get width and height for multiple images(`.bmp`) in a folder using matlab?
I know for one image

```
         Infoimage = imfinfo(filename);
         width=Infoimage.Width();
         height=Infoimage.Height();
```

The below code thatI wrote is a apart of my code which  get the width and height of each images and pass to my function :

```
         filename = getAllFiles('/my directory path')
         Infoimage = imfinfo(filename);
         width=Infoimage.Width();
         height=Infoimage.Height();
```

but the error is , and I don't know how to determine my filename type

```
Expected FILENAME to be one of these types:
char
Instead its type was cell.
Error in untitled4 (line 2)
          Infoimage = imfinfo(filename);
```

Any solution?

UPDATE

getALLFiles.m

```
function fileList = getAllFiles(dirName)

  dirData = dir(dirName);      %# Get the data for the current directory
  dirIndex = [dirData.isdir];  %# Find the index for directories
  fileList = {dirData(~dirIndex).name}';  %'# Get a list of the files
  if ~isempty(fileList)
    fileList = cellfun(@(x) fullfile(dirName,x),...  %# Prepend path to files
                       fileList,'UniformOutput',false);
  end
  subDirs = {dirData(dirIndex).name};  %# Get a list of the subdirectories
  validIndex = ~ismember(subDirs,{'.','..'});  %# Find index of subdirectories
                                               %#   that are not '.' or '..'
  for iDir = find(validIndex)                  %# Loop over valid subdirectories
    nextDir = fullfile(dirName,subDirs{iDir});    %# Get the subdirectory path
    fileList = [fileList; getAllFiles(nextDir)];  %# Recursively call getAllFiles
  end

end
```

Comment: I don't know what `getAllFiles` does, but perhaps it returns a cell array of strings with the file names? In that case you need a loop like `for k = 1:numel(filename), Infoimage{k} = imfinfo(filename{k}); end`

Comment: @LuisMendo I update getAllfiles above , i applied this loop but still I have a problem. `filelist = getAllFiles('mypath' );
           [nfilename,~]= size(filelist);`  `for idx=1:nfilename  
     
            filename = filelist{idx};
           %get the width and height of filename
            Infoimage  = imfinfo(filename);
             width=Infoimage.Width();
             height=Infoimage.Height();  end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct an imageDatastore and use the Files property in the imageDatastore to query the sizes using imfinfo as you have shown. imageDatastore lets you explore a folder recursively, as you are trying to do in the example above.

```
imds = imageDatastore(dirName,'FileExtensions',{'.bmp'},'IncludeSubfolders',true);

fileList = imds.Files
```